# Issue with python script while parsing pom file in project

Tags: python, java, xml, maven, xml-parsing

I'm having issue extracting version number using python script. Its returning `none` while running the script. Can someone help me on this ?

**Python Script:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('pom.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
releaseVersion = root.find("version")
print(releaseVersion)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <artifactId>watcher</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <name>file</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <relativePath/>
        <version>2.6.1</version> 
    </parent>

</project>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use python to extract the version number from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not taking into account that all of your elements are in a default namespace defined by `xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"` in your `<project>` element.

So you have to create your query with **this namespace**.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET    
tree = ET.parse('pom.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
NS = { 'maven' : 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0' }
releaseVersion = root.find("maven:version",NS)
print(releaseVersion.text)
```

Here `NS = { ... }` defines the namespace (in the following referred to by its prefix `maven`) used in the following XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pom.xml` has a namespace `xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"` in the project tag.

If you must search with fullname, you need to follow `{namespace}tag`

```
>> root.find("{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}version")
<Element '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}version' at 0x0000014635EC0A40>
```

But if you don't bother you can search with `{*}tag`

```
>> root.find("{*}version")
<Element '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}version' at 0x0000014635EC0A40>
```